# Why is it easier to fill a chilled metal cylinder with gases?

Tags: pressure, gas

Where I work, we chill life raft inflation cylinders before filling then with CO2, N2, and inert gases because we heard they fill easier and quicker if chilled first. Is this true?

Comment: Who did you hear this from? And why don't you ask the person who you heard this from their reason for saying it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pressure in the cylinder is related to the temperature. The higher the temperature, the higher the pressure. So the initial pressure of the cylinder for the same amount of gas would be lower in the early phases of filling it.

However... my concern about this is that they should just be filled at around the operating temperature otherwise it will heat up after a bit and the pressure will rise. This makes your pressure readings slightly inaccurate depending on how much you chill them.

For this reason, it's possible to overfill if you chill first, which could be dangerous. The only situation I can think of where chilling is crucial is filling liquid cylinders like liquid N2 or O2 because you'll waste a lot of the liquid as gas if its not cool enough before you fill it.